# plot more than one confidence interval in one plot at a particular order[SAS]

Tags: plot, sas, confidence-interval

I need to plot more than one confidence interval in one plot at a particular order.
For example, my data is:

```
N Est. Lower Upper
1  5    3     6
2  1    0     4
3  3    0     7
```

I use the following command to plot:

```
proc sgplot data=confidence;
scatter y=N x=est. / xerrorlower=lower xerrorupper=upper
      markerattrs=(symbol=circlefilled size=9);
run;
```

SAS will always plot the confidence interval at the order of N from 1 to 3. However, I need to show a trend of est. change. i.e the order I need is N=2 at first followed by N=3 and N=1 corresponding to est. = 1 3 5. Even after sorted by est., SAS still do the same things. I know I can sort and add an new order to my data to make the result I want, but I still want to show the correct N in my final plot to tell me the number of my confidence interval. Thanks.

Comment: SRSwift's answered your technical question, but I'm not convinced this is the right way to display this data.  Bar chart makes more sense to me, and perhaps your example data is just not clear but I don't understand why the Ns aren't in the proper order.

Comment: Maybe I did not clarify my question clearly. I need to make a confidence interval from each observations. So for the bar chart, every bar begin with same value(usually 0), it is not a confidence interval. The reason I want to change the original order is that the N means nothing but the order of observations, I hope I can plot the confidence interval based on the Estimation(variable names: est.),for example, I want to show the estimation is greater than 2 at the top of my plots. Hope this makes this problem clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request a discrete vertical axis, and specify the ordering method using the `yaxis` statement:

```
yaxis discreteorder = data type = discrete;
```

This will tell SAS to ignore the values in `N` and display them based on the order in which they are read from the dataset. You will have to sort your data in advance.